# Emulator Showing Old Red Phone

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb

[image]

When I select any emulator, I'm getting this weird old red phone. The screen is super small and I can't see anything. I've tried searching, but it looks like no one else has had this problem. Does anyone recognize it? My emulators did work fine, but I had to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio because it broke. After reinstalling, this is what's happening :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try genymotion as your emulator. Its faster and more stable than android studio's emulator.  Search on Google for more information.

Answer (score 5):

- Open AVD Manager in Android studio
- Select the target emulator and click edit
- Click `Show Advanced Setting`
- In the `Boot Option` section select `Cold Boot`
- Click on `Finish`

This solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Tools>Android>AVD` Manager and remove all device than add again. Hopefully this will fix your problem. I had exact issue when I moved my sdk folder.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem.

I removed all existing devices from my AVD manager and re-installed one which is required. The problem went away.